# Nmap scan of iPhone public IP address shows port 21 open

Tags: nmap, ios, ports, iphone, ftp

I'm using my iPhone personal hotspot to connect to the internet on my computer via usb connection. I don't go through any other router or connection. The phone is my only means of connecting my computer to the internet. The phone is jailbroken.

I did a `nmap` scan of my public IP address and it shows that port 21 is open. Everything I've ever read has said ftp is unsecure shouldn't be used. So it seems strange to find this port open on a public ip address. I don't use ftp for anything (that I'm aware of.)

```
$ nmap -Pn xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx --reason

Nmap scan report for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Host is up, received user-set (0.014s latency).
Not shown: 999 filtered ports
Reason: 999 no-responses
PORT   STATE SERVICE REASON
21/tcp open  ftp     syn-ack

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 6.72 seconds
```

1. Is a public ip address exclusive to a single device or are there other devices in the cellular network sharing the same ip?
2. Is there any risk that someone could gain access to the data on my phone or computer through this open ftp port?
3. And if there is a risk, how would I go about closing this port?

Comment: Run 2 tests: try using an FTP client and connect to the IP, second, disconnect your hotspot and turn off your phone and use a web-based nmap scanner like https://hackertarget.com/nmap-online-port-scanner/ - this will tell you everything. Typically, IPs are shared between many devices (read about NAT)

Comment: On a WiFi network, `nmap`ing my iPhone reveals that ports 80 and 62078 are open.

Comment: @schroeder It might not be the best idea to use a third-party web scanner to investigate a potential vulnerability.

Comment: @Arminius I'm not classifying it as a vuln. Just to see if the port persists. If persists, then it is not the OP's equipment, just an open port.

Comment: Ok I tried connecting to the IP with Cyberduck and using an online FTP test @ https://ftptest.net/. I selected anonymous login for both tests and left the password blank. The connection timed out both times. Results from web based nmap scanner: `Host is up. All 100 scanned ports on xx.xx.xx.xx are filtered`

Comment: @I0_ol Speaking as someone who's managed many wired networks, but no mobile internet networks I can't imagine that the traffic is *not* NAT'd in some way shape or form. Your public IP address might have TCP 21 open but may point to somewhere other than your phone. Why don't you connect your phone and a laptop to the same network and run the nmap scan on your phone again to confirm.

Comment: Ok I don't know if this is helpful at all but since my phone is jailbroken, I installed nmap and ran the same scan from the terminal on my phone. `All 1000 scanned ports on x.x.x.x are filtered because of 1000 no-response`. I don't know if that means anything though. As far as connecting my phone and computer to the same network, does that mean connecting them to a different network than the one (*personal hotspot usb connection*) I used originally?

Comment: False positive ? How about $ nmap -sV xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  ? Do you get a fingerprint for unknown service ?

Comment: Try connecting to it from an FTP client.  What does the banner show?

Answer (score 1):

1. Typically the IP is shared / NAT'd amongst many devices.
2. Yes it would be a risk if the port was actually open
3. It would most likely be opened by an app, so uninstall apps until the port disappears or restore back to factory defaults.